# Can a Google cloud function subscribe to an MQTT topic?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, mqtt

I am trying to listen to the MQTT commands topic. I am publishing messages to the MQTT commands topic through the Google IoT Core function sendCommandToDevice. Is there a way to use a Google cloud function to listen to the MQTT commands topic?

Here is the link to the documentation for the sendCommandToDevice function https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/reference/cloudiot/rest/v1/projects.locations.registries.devices/sendCommandToDevice

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger a Cloud Function from a message published to the IoT Core MQTT bridge.

Cloud Functions can be triggered via [Google Cloud Pub/Sub Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub).  The IoT Core MQTT bridge actually forwards messages to Cloud Pub/Sub.  By default, it forwards messages to the default telemetry topic specified when creating a device registry.  Note:  it is possible to [configure multiple topics](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/devices#creating_a_device_registry_with_multiple_pubsub_topics) as well.

Putting this together, when you create a Cloud Function, you will then configure a the [Cloud Pub/Sub trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub) using the Pub/Sub topic associated with your device registry as described above.

Comment: Thanks, we (I'm working with OP) have had no trouble intercepting topics coming *from* the device on the telemetry topic. The issue is that we want to have something listening in on the commands topic going *to* the device. As near as we can tell, the sendCommandToDevice() function goes straight to the broker, no PubSub involved. We can create code that connects to the broker directly, but it seems to hear only commands to itself...i.e., we can subscribe to "/devices/my-device/commands/#" and see messages, but we see nothing if we subscribe to "/devices/+/commands/#", or even "#".

Comment: Oh - sorry - misread the question.  I'm pretty sure IoT Core MQTT does not support wildcards in arbitrary parts of the topic string.  So you'll need to implement your own solution, something like setting up a Pub/Sub topic to which all commands are sent and then trigger a function which relays them to the appropriate device via MQTT and does whatever else you'd like.  Or have two listeners/functions (one to relay the command and the other to do whatever else you like).

Comment: Yes, if it were possible to set up a PubSub topic that got all commands to the devices that would be lovely. We have not been able to do that.